# Lumen - how to import external libraries properly

Tags: import, dependencies, libraries, require, lumen

I'm trying to import PHPExcel library into my Lumen project and I'm doing it by this tutorial:

http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/

What I exactly did is:

1. Copied content of PHPexcel/Classes folder into App/Libraries folder (so that in App/Libraries is `PHPExcel.php` file and `PHPExcel` subfolder).
2. Added `namespace App\Libraries;` at the beginning of `PHPExcel.php` file
3. Added `use App\Libraries\PHPExcel;` into my controller file
4. Calling `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileName);` in controller

But I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found

What am I doing wrong and how to import the library properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add App\Libraries to your class map. In composer.json update the autoload classmap to include that directory.

```
{
...
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
       },
        "classmap": [            
            "app/Models",
            "app/Libraries"
        ]
    },
...
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I added it to `autoload` and `autoload-dev` also, then `composer dump-autoload`, but nothing has changed - still the same error.

Comment: My class also shares a name with the file containing it. so in your case. My class would be PHPExcel.

Also, per item #1 - Why do you need a file and subdir in Libraries called PHPExcel? What is contained in the subdir?

Comment: PHPexcel.php is main class that requires and uses other classes in PHPExcel directory.

Comment: If PHPExcel.php is in the PHPExcel dir you will need that reflected in your namespaces, which it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: No, php excel is not in PHPExcel directory. It is in Libraries directory (alongside PHPExcel directory)